# Calculating the standard matrix for orthogonal projection, 3 way matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

I'm trying to calculate the standard matrix for orthogonal projection using the formula for the matrix P=$A(A^T A)^ {-1} A^T$.

My approach has diverged from the supplied answer to this question:
[image: my_attempt]
[image: supplied]

It seems that I've done the working for the inner part ($A^T A$) correctly but when it comes to multiplying the outer parts I have a very different answer. I've produced a $1 \times 1$ matrix while the supplied answer has a $3 \times 3$ matrix.

I really just started at the left and multiplied the outer A by the inverse of the inner multiplication: $\frac{1}{21}$, then multiplied the resulting vector with the outer $A^T$ .

For some reason I can't get Wolfram Alpha to calculate the matrix product either, it stops after the 1st multiplication [Wolfram Alpha Equation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B2%7D,%20%7B-1%7D,%20%7B4%7D%7D*(%7B%7B21%7D%7D%5E-1)*%7B2,%20-1,%204%7D)

Would anyone be able to let me know what my mistake has been, and how I can properly approach this type of question in the future?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make a mistake when multiplying the column vector with the row vector. Remember that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\ b
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
c & d
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
ac & ad \\ bc & bd
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I think I might a bit tired, but I'm still not sure why Wolfram is not generating that answer, even when I split up the equations into separate inputs.

Comment: You forget the parentheses around the last row vector. Now it is interpreted as a one dimensional array instead of a two dimensional matrix (of which the length of the first dimension is 1). So try {{2, -1, 4}} instead of {2, -1, 4}.

Comment: Argh, thank you so much! That's got it, I'm ashamed to say how much time I spent trying to see the problem!

Comment: You are welcome. These mistakes are a good way to learn :)